# Create string with ESC characters

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I can initialise string with escape characer like `std:string s="\065"` and this creates `"A"` character. But what if I need `ASCI character = 200`. `std:string s="\200"` not working. Why?

Comment: because you can't. use `std::string s = std::string() + char(200)...` etc.

Comment: `std::string s = "\0310";` should give you the ASCII character with value 200. Remember that leading `0` means "octal".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"\065"` does not create `"A"` but `"5"`.  `"\065"` is interpreted as an octal number, which is decimal 53, which is character `'5'`.

`std::string s = "\xc8"` ; (hex) gives me the character 200.

Comment: So, I can use octal and hex expression. But why there is no decimal?

Comment: Because there is no syntax defined in the language for using an escape sequence for a decimal number.

Comment: because computers and programmers tend to think in hex for character codes. Octal is the equivalent of hex from the olden days when there were 6/9/12... bit machines (multiples of three not four)

Answer (score 0):

Because `\065` is actually in octal form; to specify character 200, try `\310` or `\xc8`. And BTW, `\065` is not character `A` but is `5`.